# Filling gaps in lines and measuring their width

Tags: python, opencv, line

I have the video with white lines on the basketball field. Example picture:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92bKJ.jpg)

and I would like to to take out only white lines and fill as much as I can, and clear the rest of the noises. Now after many attempts i get:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jfcO.png)

For clearing everything else except white(because for me it is the best resault taking only white color didn't work well):

```py
low = np.array([0, 42, 0])
high = np.array([179, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(frame, low, high)
```

and second and better result after using Floodfill:
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z79rv.png)
code:

```py
im_in = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th, im_th = cv.threshold(im_in, 220, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
im_floodfill = im_th.copy()
h, w = im_th.shape[:2]
mask2 = np.zeros((h + 2, w + 2), np.uint8)
cv2.floodFill(im_floodfill, mask2, (0, 0), 255);
im_floodfill_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(im_floodfill)
im_out = im_th | im_floodfill_inv
```

I have tried skeletonizing and morphological closing and similar functions but it is not what I would like to achieve. Also maybe someone knows what is the best way to count the size of width of line(for example that which is in the middle of the video/picture?). Thank You for help!